# Python BeautifulSoup - Exclude find() tag and replace DIVs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the code below. It successfully gets the content I need but also includes the tag I am searching for. How do I exclude this?

Additionally, the content is is using DIV tags rather than P tags. How do I amend all `<div>....</div>` tags to be `<p>...</p>`

**Example Output**

```
<div class="article__body"><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div></div>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>
```

**CODE:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/news/1234")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)


print soup.find("h2", {"class": "article__title"})
print ("=================================")
print soup.find("div", {"class": "article__body"})
print ("=================================")
print soup.find("div", {"class": "article__image"})
```

Comment: "_but also includes the tag I am searching for. How do I exclude this?_" Can you elaborate?

Comment: Look at desired output Vs actual output